# c# request FormClosing

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I have a form to ask for some data. At leaving of an input field (TextBox, DGV) the appropriate _Validating methode or _CellValueChanged methode is called.

If I want to end the program this methode is called, too - **before** the _FormClosing methode is called.

How can I fin out whether the program branches into the _FormClosing methode or not?

```
private void txb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    doLog("Text 1");
}

private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    doLog("Text 2");
}

private void doLog(string txt)
{
    // this is first called at closing...
    if( [FormClosing is active] )
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do someting different
    }
}

private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // ... and this but later
    // Write the Logfile
}
```

How have I to replace [FormClosing is active] to get to the right result?

I tried so

```
if ( this.FormClosing== true )
```

and so

```
this.FormClosing +=new FormClosingEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosing);
```

and so

```
FormClosingEventHandler cl = new FormClosingEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosing);
```

but I always was in a dead end.

Comment: i coudn't understand your question at all, please be more specic and clearer

Comment: I have to stop the doLog if _FormClosing is to be called. 
But when I want to end the program first the object having the focus will start the _Validation (and calls the do Log) before the _FormClosing starts.

Answer (score 1):

`this.FormClosing` is an event that gets triggered once your form starts closing (like clicking the close button), hence the name. You need your application to register that event like so:

```
 this.FormClosing +=new FormClosingEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosing);
```

This insures that once the FormClosing event gets triggered, your `MyForm_FormClosing` will be called.

You can create a flag like `bool bIsFormClosing` and set that flag once your closing function get called.

Edit:

As I understand now by reviewing your answer and your comments, you want to know in your doLog function if the form is closing.

Here is another approach

`

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    private bool bIsClosing = false;
    Private bool bClosingHandled = false;

    public YourClass()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.FormClosing +=
           new FormClosingEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosing);
    }

    private void txb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        doLog("Text 1");
    }

    private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender,
        DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        doLog("Text 2");
    }

    private void doLog(string txt)
    {
        // this is first called at closing...
        if( bIsClosing )
        {
            // Do something
            bClosingHandled = true;
            this.close(); 
        }
        else
        {
            // Do someting different
        }
    }

    private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        If(!bClosingHandled)
        {
          bIsClosing = true;
          e.Cancel = true;
          return;
        }

        // Write the Logfile
        doLog("whatever");
    }
}`
```

This approach uses two flags... When you first receive a close event, you set the `bIsClosing` flag to true, cancels the event and return. Then once your dolog function get called, you force the close operation.

Comment: As you see, this event handler is already there. And it's too late to set a flag there.

Comment: Check the new approach in my answer

Comment: When I end the program 1) the current object looses the focus -> _Validating event is called -> doLog is called. Now I have to know, wether the program terminating or not. After this 2) the _FormClosing event is called. Thou your solution would'n be successfull.

Comment: So your validate code gets called before the close event gets triggered?

Comment: @MartinS what are you trying to accomplish man... If you want to detect the closing event before it triggers, then I'm afraid you are out of luck

Comment: I could change the other code, so that I don't need a solution any longer.
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    private bool bIsClosing = false;

    public YourClass()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.FormClosing +=
           new FormClosingEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosing);
    }

    private void txb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        doLog("Text 1");
    }

    private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender,
        DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        doLog("Text 2");
    }

    private void doLog(string txt)
    {
        // this is first called at closing...
        if( bIsClosing )
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Do someting different
        }
    }

    private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        bIsClosing = true;
        // Write the Logfile
        doLog("whatever");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought I could do so, but it is too late to set the bIsClosing in MyForm_FormClosing.
The _Validating and so the called doLog is earlier!